# Filter methods in WCF ServiceContract

Tags: c#, wcf

I realized multiple ServiceContracts in one ServiceHost. The service is accessible internal and external of the network, and the access is granted through IP-based method attributes:

```
[OperationContract]
[IPAuthentication(RequiredPermission = PermissionLevels.ExternalRead)]
bool Ping();
```

This works great, but it is confusing for the client to see all methods but only several methods are not access restricted, the others throw an HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized exception.

How can I inherit, extend or change the ServiceContractAttribute to achieve a filtered method list in client's WSDL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control WSDL generation through [IWsdlExportExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iwsdlexportextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

A good example can be found here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/10/06/wcf-extensibility-wsdl-export-extension.aspx

Comment: Thanks @nodots for your help. Depending on your answer and a full example with all methods [GetCodeSamples](http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/9FE9D387/3892B3EF) I built an IPAuthServiceContract-Attribute doing the job.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to iterate over all wsdl files to touch any object:

```
public void ExportEndpoint(WsdlExporter exporter, WsdlEndpointConversionContext context)
{
    foreach (ServiceDescription wsdl in exporter.GeneratedWsdlDocuments)
    {
        List<string> messageNamesToRemove;
        RemoveOperationsFromPortTypes(wsdl, out messageNamesToRemove);

        List<string> policiesToRemove;
        RemoveOperationsFromBindings(wsdl, out policiesToRemove);

        RemoveWsdlMessages(wsdl, messageNamesToRemove);
        RemoveOperationRelatedPolicies(wsdl, policiesToRemove);
    }
}
```

And if all methods are hidden remove empty contracts from PortTypes and Bindings:

```
private void RemoveOperationsFromPortTypes(ServiceDescription wsdl, out List<string> messageNamesToRemove)
{
    messageNamesToRemove = new List<string>();
    var emptyPorts = new List<System.Web.Services.Description.PortType>();
    foreach (System.Web.Services.Description.PortType portType in wsdl.PortTypes)
    {
        for (int i = portType.Operations.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            ...

            if (portType.Operations.Count == 0)
                emptyPorts.Add(portType);
        }
    }

    foreach (var emptyPort in emptyPorts)
    {
        wsdl.PortTypes.Remove(emptyPort);
    }
}

private void RemoveOperationsFromBindings(ServiceDescription wsdl, out List<string> policiesToRemove)
{
    policiesToRemove = new List<string>();
    var emptyBindings = new List<System.Web.Services.Description.Binding>();
    foreach (System.Web.Services.Description.Binding binding in wsdl.Bindings)
    {
        for (int i = binding.Operations.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            ...
        }

        if (binding.Operations.Count == 0)
            emptyBindings.Add(binding);
    }

    foreach (var emptyBinding in emptyBindings)
    {
        wsdl.Bindings.Remove(emptyBinding);
    }
}
```